# Convert list of ints to its little-endian representation in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, endianness

I would like to use C# to convert a list of ints to its little-endian representation. Can you please offer an elegant way? looking at other the answers, I can see bit shift and such. I just wonder if there is another way that will result in more readable code

**Examples:**

[55,9] -> 2359,

[70,15] -> 3910

**Extra info:**
If you are familiar with NodeJS, it should be the same idea like:

> new Buffer.from([55,9]).readUInt16LE(0) -> 2359

[buf.readUInt16LE(offset[, noAssert])](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint16le_offset_noassert)

*I been asked to add give some background to my question (see comment by @mjwills):*

I am listening to messages on the MOM (messaging oriented middleware). The payload is JSON string. Once I receive a msg, I read the payload which look like the following:

"power": [55, 9]

This array represent an integer that I need to work with downstream. As a result, I want to publish an event like the following:

"power": 2359

I hope that helps.

**Update:**
After digging around I found this to be working just fine:

> BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { 55, 9 }, 0) //2359

[Here is more info and example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16.aspx)

1. Is that a good way to convert? or do you see issues with that approach?

This line is an excerpt from the docs:

> The order of bytes in the array must reflect the endianness of the computer system's architecture

If I target my code to AnyCPU, and it runs on the cloud, I do not have much control on the architecture.

2. Is there a way around it? other than worry about the target architecture?

Comment: Generally we do not deal with "how is it represented in memory" in C#. It is one of those things best left to the Runtime. If you want to do bit pattern manipulation, the first question should be: "Why am I not doing this in Native C++/Assembler/some other low level langage?"

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I do not care how it is represented in memory. If a string is UTF-8, UTF-16 in little or big endian in my RAM? I do not care. The Runtime get's to decide that. If I do network communication, then how a number has to be transmited (wich type/encoding/endian format) is part of the Networking Protocoll used. Mostly existin (de)serialsiation code deals with this.

Comment: I can think of 300000 different reasons to require this in _any language_. Binary file formats like images, audio, custom data formats, emulation, graphics programming ..even some DB sharding techniques use bit-level manipulation for shard keys .... you can't dismiss the OP's question because he's tagged a "low level" question with the C# tag. You have no idea why the OP requires this (and it is a legit question) so I find your comment very strange and dismissive.

Comment: I'm going to say **NO** - just learn how Bit Shifts work, the syntax is readable.

Comment: question updated as per @mjwills request.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead Thank you for your effort so far. You are spot on with your comments.

Comment: You may wish to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx to determine whether to reverse the data before calling `BitConverter.ToInt16`.

Answer (score 2):

> ..another way that will result in more readable code..

..not really. That is, unless you want to just wrap it in a function. Here is a 5 minute throw-together that probably misses an edge case to get you started. I've intentionally split out the shifting this way to make it clear what is happening to hopefully help you see it easier:

```
static int ReadInt32(byte[] arr) {
    if (arr.Length > 4) {
        throw new Exception("Can't read a 32-bit integer that contains more than 32 bits");
    }

    if (arr.Length < 4) {
        // zero pad the rest
        var buffer = new byte[4];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            buffer[i] = arr[i];

        arr = buffer;
    }

    var b1 = (int)arr[0];
    var b2 = (int)arr[1];
    var b3 = (int)arr[2];
    var b4 = (int)arr[3];

    return b1 | b2 << 8 | b3 << 16 | b4 << 24;
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = new byte[] { 55, 9 };
var b = new byte[] { 70, 15 };

var c = ReadInt32(a);
var d = ReadInt32(b);

Console.WriteLine("Results: {0}, {1}", c , d); // 2359, 3910
```

There are probably lots of nice libraries that do this all for you already though (I can't think of any off the top of my head .. but will happily edit them in if someone else mentions any).